# MS Access 2016 UPDATE query with ALIKE

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I'm trying to run the following UPDATE query in MS Access 2016 VBA:

```
UPDATE M_Subscriber
    SET M_Subscriber.RatingID = t.RatingID
    FROM
        ( SELECT M_Subscriber.ID AS SubscriberID, E_SubscriberRating.ID AS RatingID
              FROM M_Subscriber, E_SubscriberRating
              WHERE M_Subscriber.Labels ALIKE '%' & E_SubscriberRating.Description & '%'
        ) AS t
    WHERE M_Subscriber.ID = t.SubscriberID
```

However, when trying to execute it I get a "syntax error (missing operator) in query expression" error.

I know that the SELECT part of the query by itself works just as expected (though using LIKE instead of ALIKE does not, even when using * for the wildcard...).

I've also tried this version of the query:

```
UPDATE M_Subscriber
    SET M_Subscriber.RatingID = E_SubscriberRating.ID
    FROM M_Subscriber
        INNER JOIN E_SubscriberRating
        ON M_Subscriber.Labels ALIKE '%' & E_SubscriberRating.Description & '%'
```

But again the same error message (and again, a standalone SELECT statement using the INNER JOIN works just fine).

Some info on what I'm trying to do:

I have a field of labels (just at string of various words) for my subscribers (in M_Subscriber) and one of those words can be a rating. On the other hand I have a table (E_SubscriberRatings) of all possible words for ratings (E_SubscriberRating.Description). I'm now trying to set the M_Subscriber.RatingID field based on the ID of the SubscriberRating whose description shows up in the M_Subscriber.Labels field (if it actually contains any such description).

At this point, I've really run out of ideas what to tweak to figure out what I'm doing wrong. I've found various examples that join by column = column but none that join using LIKE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MS Access does not use `FROM` in `UPDATE` queries unlike other SQL dialects. Consider `UPDATE...INNER JOIN` (a method it shares with MySQL) and do so with table aliases:

```sql
UPDATE M_Subscriber m 
INNER JOIN E_SubscriberRating e
ON m.Labels ALIKE '%' & e.Description & '%'
SET m.RatingID = e.ID;
```

Alternatively, with `WHERE` clause:

```sql
UPDATE M_Subscriber m, E_SubscriberRating e
SET m.RatingID = e.ID
WHERE m.Labels ALIKE '%' & e.Description & '%';
```

Comment: thanks! Can you suggest any resource where I could look this up in the future to become more self-sufficient (since my google-fu obviously failed me this time around...)?

Comment: There's actually no MSN documentation on Access SQL syntax regarding `UPDATE` between two tables. However, had you used the Query designer to graphically build the update query you will see the syntax in SQL view.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this syntax:

```
UPDATE M_Subscriber INNER JOIN
       E_SubscriberRating
       ON M_Subscriber.Labels ALIKE '%' & E_SubscriberRating.Description & '%'
    SET M_Subscriber.RatingID = E_SubscriberRating.ID;
```